# print the pattern using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

i want the print the below pattern **using recursion and do not have to use any loops(strictly).**

```
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * *     * * * * * *
* * * * *         * * * * *
* * * *             * * * *
* * *                 * * *
* *                     * *
*                         *
* *                     * *
* * *                 * * * 
* * * *             * * * *
* * * * *         * * * * *
* * * * * *     * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * *
```

i have did it without using recursion

```
n = 7
for i in range(n,0,-1):
    for j in range(i,0,-1):
        print("*",end=" ")
    for j in range(2*(n-i)):
        print(" ",end=" ")
    for j in range(i,0,-1):
        print("*",end=" ")
    print()

for i in range(1,n):
    for j in range(i+1):
        print("*",end=" ")
    for j in range(2*(n-i-1)):
        print(" ",end=" ")
    for j in range(i+1):
        print("*",end=" ")
    print()
```

can anyone help in printing the same patter **using recursion and without using any loops(strictly)**

i have tried using recursion but unable to print it properly and unable to visualize the code any further
code using recursion:

```
def print_pattern(n, row=0):
    if row == n:
        return
    print("* "*(n - row) + "  "*(2*row) + "* "*(n - row))
    print_pattern(n, row + 1)
    if row != 0:
        print("* "*(n - row) + "  "*(2*row) + "* "*(n - row))

n = 5
print_pattern(n)
```

Comment: If you want to learn recursion, I strongly suggest choosing a language other than python. It's one of the worst languages for recursion. For most problems, in python, the answer to the question "How to do this with recursion?" will inevitably be "Don't use recursion for this".

Comment: @Stef How is python worse than other languages in this context?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The check should be `row != n - 1`:

```
def print_pattern(n, row=0):
    if row == n:
        return
    print("* " * (n - row) + "  " * (2 * row) + "* " * (n - row))
    print_pattern(n, row + 1)
    if row != n - 1:
        print("* " * (n - row) + "  " * (2 * row) + "* " * (n - row))


n = int(input('Number of lines:'))
print_pattern(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern always stays the same you could save it in a variable using `var ='''pattern'''`

In this case it would look like this:

```
pattern = '''* * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * *     * * * * * *
* * * * *         * * * * *
* * * *             * * * *
* * *                 * * *
* *                     * *
*                         *
* *                     * *
* * *                 * * * 
* * * *             * * * *
* * * * *         * * * * *
* * * * * *     * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * *'''

print(pattern)
```

Comment: the pattern is of same type, the only thing that varies is no of rows and columns with user input

Answer (score -1):

Use only row != -1 your code will work properly

```
def print_pattern(n, row=0):
    if row == n:
        return
    print("* "*(n - row) + "  "*(2*row) + "* "*(n - row))
    print_pattern(n, row + 1)
    if row != -1:
        print("* "*(n - row) + "  "*(2*row) + "* "*(n - row))

n = 7
print_pattern(n)
```

Comment: please write it into a code block, would be easier to understand and also the value of n is not fixed, it is a user input.

Comment: `if row != -1` is redundant. `row` starts from 0 and increases. Just remove the check.

Comment: it prints an extra row in the middle half. i.e after the end of upper half it again print 1 star and spaces and 1 star. this line is extra.